# Printing ASCIIvalue of char gives unexpected output

Tags: c, char, printf

I know, there are some solved solutions here on stackoverflow. But I don't know why doesn't mine one work.

```
            char *ink[90]
            strcpy(ink, "hi");
            printf("stepiii %c \n",ink[0] );
            printf("ascii %d\n",ink[0] );
```

Instead of "ascii 104" returns bad value like

> "ascii 26984"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read the warnings....`strcpy(ink, "hi");`????

Comment: Also not that `%d` is the wrong format-specifier for a `char` argument. Use `%hhd`.

Comment: @Olaf Doesn't the default argument promotion take care of that?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Basically yes, but still the format string type should always match the argument type. Not sure if a compiler will warn about that, though.

Comment: @Olaf That's what I thought, too. Thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: @Olaf "%d is the wrong format-specifier for a char argument." is not wrong per C for a `char`, but `printf("ascii %d\n",ink[0] );` is wrong because `ink[0]` is a pointer.

Comment: @chux: I actually commented on the intend, not the implementation. That is covered in the answers. Should have made that more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,

```
  char *ink[90]
```

is wrong. You don't need an array of pointers, as seen in the rest of the snippet. Change that to

```
  char ink[90]= {0};
```

In case you're wondering about the previous output, that code invoked [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, the output is essentially meaningless and MUST not be trusted.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an array of pointers and copying characters to it. You need an array of `char` and copy the characters to it, like this

```
char ink[90]
strcpy(ink, "hi");
printf("stepiii %c \n", ink[0]);
printf("ascii %d\n", ink[0]);
```

What you had is wrong because `ink[0]` is the address of the first *pointer* in the array, you initialized the array with `strcpy()` which should trigger an *incompatible pointers type* warning, enable compilation warnings to avoid this.

The way it is in your code it invokes *undefined behavior* and your program could crash or anything could happen. The printed value doesn't make sense.